# python class design for each Person has N Projects, and each Project has M things

Tags: python

if the scenario be:
the are `Person's`, each `Person` can have N `Projects`, each `Project` may have M `Things`.
so far I implemented class as below:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.projects=Project()

class Project():
    def __init__(self):
        self.project=[]

some_one=Person()
some_one.projects.project.extend(["project1", "project2"])
print(some_one.projects.project)

['project1', 'project2']
```

the problem is when I want to connect a `project` to `things`

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.projects=Project()

class Project():
    def __init__(self):
        self.project=[]
        self.things=Thing()

class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.thing="thing"

some_one=Person()
some_one.projects.project.extend(["project1", "project2"])
```

I want something like:

```
some_one.projects.project1.things.thing1="some_one's project1's thing1"
```

Answer (score 1):

If a `Person` can have many `Project`, it should hold a collection of `Project`.
If a `Project` can have many `Thing`, it should hold a collection of `Thing'.
Then you can address the attributes the way you described.

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.projects = []   # a collection of Project

class Project():
    def __init__(self):
        self.things = []     # a collection of Thing

class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        # this thing attributes
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `Person` should have a list of `Project`, and `Project` should have a list of `Thing`.

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.projects = []

class Project():
    def __init__(self):
        self.things = []

class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.thing = 'thing'
```

So for example

```
thing_a = Thing()
thing_b = Thing()
thing_c = Thing()

project_a = Project()
project_a.things = [thing_b, thing_c]

project_b = Project()
project_b.things = [thing_a, thing_b]

someone = Person()
someone.projects = [project_a, project_b]
```

Then you could say

```
>>> someone.projects[0].things[0].thing
thing
```